# Reading, writing and saving data Android app

Tags: android, file, save

So I am trying to make an app that saves a text file sa device and uses the timestamp as the file name then yung same file would be sent to the computer to a specific folder.
I am trying to start off by having the file saved and read in my device. My code runs but when I enter the data and press the save button to save the file, the app crashes.

Posted is the logcat of the app. Can't seem to find what's wrong. Any help would be useful. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Post your code. I see there's a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Look through your code for a `string.length()` call. The stack trace indicates that the string is null.

Answer (score 3):

Check on the second to the last line of the error message from logcat you provided with your link. It says `NullPointerException` . You must have called `<your string variable>.length()` from a null variable.